# Salesforce1 stopped supporting geolocation

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, geolocation

I have a Visualforce page enabled for Lightning, which has one button that gets the geolocation in coordinates and shows the location in a Google map embedded in the page.

This was working until last Friday, but now I get this error:

> Geolocation has been disabled in this document by feature policy

When I call the method `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` in the browser, it worked fine. I also checked the permissions in the mobile.

Is this feature no longer supported? If not, is there any workaround?

Comment: I tweaked your post for you a bit. In the future, please try to be more specific about your questions than asking *"can anyone help me?"*